# "app's tab on the user's timeline"?

Tags: facebook-apps, timeline

[This blog post](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/625/) says:

> **Stories In Timeline App Tab**
>
> Stories published from an app using Feed dialog or Graph API will now show in the app's tab on the user's timeline. This is consistent with Open Graph actions published from an app showing in the app's tab.

The text "*the app's tab on the user's timeline*" caught my attention. Is there such thing as an app's tab in a user's timeline? I didn't even know there were tabs in user's timelines at all. I searched the documentation but only found about tab apps for pages, not for user's timelines. Am I missing something, or the blog post just uses incorrect terms?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the same thing; in this context the blog post is referring to a view of a user's timeline which is filtered to only showposts from a specific app.
This is selected on facebook.com by choosing an app from the 'more' selector on the timeline, beside Timeline, About, Friends and Photos

Also, that blog post is 15 months old, you should try not to rely on the blog posts unless they're recent, the main documentation should be used when building your app

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yes, that post is quite old. I usually don't rely on old stuff (I've been using FB platform for 3 years and I know things are constantly changing), but I came across this post while cleaning up an old to-do list.